# Getting the average of a list of values based on the least value for each group and not considering zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the least number of days that listed for each ticket+ add them up and divide them per distinct number of tickets that I have (not considering zero values). Can anyone help me on this, please?

My data looks like the following:

[image]

Here is the formula that I have:

```
=Sum(min([Build Complete Days] In([Ticket ID])))/[Ticket_Count]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like two levels of aggregation:

```
select avg(min_cd * 1.0) as avg_min_days_per_ticket
from (select ticket_id, min(complete_days) as min_cd
      from t
      where complete_days > 0
      group by ticket_id
    ) t;
```

Comment: Can you please explain what (min_cd * 1.0)  does here? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @nina_dev . . . You don't specify your database.  Some databases return an integer for the average of an integer.  You probably want something with decimal points.

Answer (score 0):

Select the min `completeddays` for each `ticketid` with `NOT EXISTS` and get the average:

```
select avg(t.completeddays) averagedays
from tablename t
where t.completeddays > 0 and not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where ticketid = t.ticketid and completeddays > 0 and completeddays < t.completeddays
)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what this part do?
  @forpas not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where ticketid = t.ticketid and completeddays > 0 and completeddays < t.completeddays

Comment: not exists eliminates for each ticketid all the rows for which exists a row with the same ticketid and greater completeddays, so the row that is left is the one with the min completeddays.